# How to import or upload data into database model in Django using CSV file?

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

I  created a  wold map based web app, when user clicks on a particular country it return information related to a particular country:

The model running behind the app is:

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class CountryDetails(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    T_attack = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="attack")
    year = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    Deaths = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    NEWS_ID = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="NEWS_ID")


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Deaths
```

And holds data like given bellow,  which is a Demo data faded by admin user interface:

```
name   T_attack   year  Deaths  News_ID

India    12       2006   12       NDTV
India    110      2009   1        DEAN
PAKISTAN 9        2002   10       XYZT
PAKISTAN 11       2021   11       XXTV
India    12       2023   120      NDNV
India    10       2012   12       DEAN
PAKISTAN 12       2022   12       DLRS
Canada   1        2001   1        DLTV
USA      2        2011   13       NTTV
```

I have completed the app  now I have a .csv file that contains data in similar format and around 500 rows.

In few posts, I have seen some suggestions which says django-import-export is a right choice for this purpose but,  unfortunately I am not able to implement the import method of "Django-import-export" for this purpose.

hence, I  decides   to write a manual code to loop over all the rows using "Django-shell" like this

```
f = open(my_csv_file.csv)
lines = f.readlines() 
For i,l in enumerate(lines):
    l.split(',')[0]
    c = Country.objects.create(name=l.split(',')[0])
    CountryDetails.objects.create(country=c,T_attack=l.split(',')[1],year=l.split(',')[2],Deaths=l.split(',')[3],News_ID=l.split(',')[4])
```

But this method massed up the scenario and not able to add the  data as I had added with Admin inter phase manually.